# Иконка Instagram в Vector Drawable

Tags: android, vector

Svg иконка instagram имеет градиенты, видимо из-за этого не получается импортировать в проект в виде Vector Drawable, пробовал импорт и через http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ и через Android Studio.
Посоветуйте путь как внедрить иконку instagram в проект с градиентами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android не поддерживает градиенты в векторе. [Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) так и говорит:

> Not supported:
>
> Color fills and strokes other than solid, such as gradients.

Чтобы добавить с градиентами - используйте обычные растровые иконки для каждого разрешения экрана.